# Limit $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{13^n+(-5)^n}{4\dot\ 13^n+(-11)^n }$

Tags: limits

How can I calculate this limit ? $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{13^n+(-5)^n}{4\dot\ 13^n+(-11)^n }$$

Comment: Surely you mean $n\to\infty$? Otherwise you're taking the limit of a constant.

Comment: Ben thanks,yes, its n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{13^n+(-5)^n}{4\dot\ 13^n+(-11)^n }=\frac{1+\left(-\frac{5}{13}\right)^n}{4+\left(-\frac{11}{13}\right)^n }$$
 and note that $\left|{-\frac{5}{13}} \right|<1,\;\;\left|{-\frac{11}{13}} \right|<1.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{13^n+(-5)^n}{4\dot\ 13^n+(-11)^n}=
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{13^n+(-5)^n}{4\dot\ 13^n+(-11)^n}\frac{13^{-n}}{13^{-n}}
=\cdots
$$